# Page scrolls to top instead of starting from the top using Vue and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-router

From whatever position I'm at, when I go to a new page, it scrolls to the top of each page instead of starting from the top.
When I changed the bootstrap cdn to version 4.6, not 5, it stopped, but my layout was affected.

Neither

```
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition;
    } else {
        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        };
    }
  }
```

nor

```
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // Start page at top
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

worked

How do I use bootstrap v5, but prevent this default scroll behavior?

Comment: For now, I used bootstrap v4.6, followed by the CDN for the bootstrap v5 grid only to take care of layout, till I'm able to sort the scroll behavior